Install PHP cURL on Debian Jessie running PHP 7.0.33
Before we get started, if we could bypass the whole you "need to update" please? Thank you.
I would like to install the PHP cURL extension on a Debian server (Jessie) running PHP 7.0.33
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
Release:    8.10
Codename:   jessie


# php -v
PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u11 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2021 18:15:58) ( NTS )

# apt install php-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpth20 libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libxapian22 python-acme python-augeas python-certbot
  python-cffi-backend python-configargparse python-configobj python-cryptography python-dialog python-dnspython
  python-enum34 python-funcsigs python-idna python-ipaddress python-mock python-ndg-httpsclient python-openssl
  python-parsedatetime python-pbr python-psutil python-pyasn1 python-pyicu python-requests python-rfc3339 python-tz
  python-urllib3 python-zope.component python-zope.event python-zope.interface python3.4 python3.4-minimal
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php7.0-curl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-curl php7.0-curl
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 526 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 130 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 php7.0-curl amd64 7.0.33-0+deb9u11
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.74.132 80]
Err:2 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 php-curl all 1:7.0+49
  404  Not Found [IP: 78.129.164.123 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-curl_7.0.33-0+deb9u11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.74.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-curl_7.0+49_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 78.129.164.123 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I've spent hours trying all sorts including:

Uncommenting extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini
Adding curl.so in the /usr/php folder

Is there I was I can do this? Maybe installing it manually?
Thanks.

This question is similar to: Docker - Packages 404 Not Found From node:8-jessie. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@shingo Thank you. I updated the sources.list as per the answer on the post you referenced and run apt update and then apt install php-curl (and apt install php7.0-curl) and got E: Unable to locate package php-curl

I can find the package at http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-curl_7.0.33-0+deb9u12_amd64.deb Have you tried apt search curl?

@shingo Yes, it brings up a reference to an old install pf php5 as follows php5-curl/oldoldstable 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u12 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.6.33+dfsg-0+deb8u1]   CURL module for php5

I saw that all php7.0 packages are built for deb9u12, and your php-cli is also built for deb9u11, but you are on debian 8.10. So did you force apt to install this version of php7.0 in the past?

Jessie came with PHP5, so you must have added 7 from some other source. It looks like you used the Stretch packages for this. At this point, you'll probably have to install from source. If you're lucky, you can just do pecl install curl

Thanks for your replies, I "inherited" it like this, so yes, I assume PHP 7.0 was somehow installed on it. I can see commented our Jessie references in /etc/apt/sources.list so I'm guessing this is what happened.
